# What should I do to be able to test a custom translated function in Sqlite in-memory database?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

In my team's project, we use sql-server as database and sqlite as integration test's database.

I really want to use  `DayOfWeek` to group things.
So I created a translation In `DBContext` class like so

```cs
...
public int? DayOfWeek(DateTimeOffset date) => throw new Exception();
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    var DayOfWeekMethodInfo = typeof(DBContext).GetMethod(nameof(DBContext.DayOfWeek));
    if (Database.IsSqlServer())
    {
         builder
             .HasDbFunction(DayOfWeekMethodInfo)
             .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("DATEPART", new[]
             {
                 new SqlFragmentExpression("weekday"), 
                    args.ToArray()[0]
             }, typeof(int?), null));
    else
    {
         builder
            .HasDbFunction(DayOfWeekMethodInfo)
            .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("strftime", new[]
            {
                new SqlFragmentExpression("'%w'"),
                    args.ToArray()[0]
            }, typeof(int?), null));
     }
}
```

In use:

```cs
public IQueryable<TransactionCount> SomeRandomFunction()
{
    return from t in QueryAllTransaction()
           group t by new 
           {
                dayOfWeek = dbConText.DayOfWeek(t.transactionDate)
           }
           into g
           select new TransactionCount
           {
                dayOfWeek = g.Key.dayOfWeek,
                count = g.Count()
           };
}
```

When debuging (sql-server), the code is working fine. But in the test, it thrown error

> System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet could not be translated. Either rewrite the query
> in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

What should I do to be able to test the function in Sqlite in-memory database?

Comment: Try to make `DayOfWeek` static

Comment: You should use the same database engine for testing and production.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv not working, It thrown the same error.

Comment: @Shawn Currently we have a lot of test that working fine, I don't know if it's worth changing. I'm finding the way that not changing the database provider.